# How to code this constraint in CPLEX?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, cplex, constraint, scheduling

$$\sum_{j\in M}\sum_{k=i}^{\rm until}x_{aijk}\cdot b_{kj}=d_{ai},\quad\forall i\in N,\forall a\in B\cap A_1;{\rm until}=\min(i+v_a,n)$$ How to code this linear program in CPLEX?

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. Please 1) show what you have attempted and/or 2) provide more background on the context of the constraint and for future posts, 3) take a look at [this guide](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-do-i-use-mathjax-on-this-site) on how to format mathematical equations in MathJax.

Comment: You do not code a constraint in "CPLEX"; you code it in a modeling language or a programming language via one of CPLEX's APIs. Are you using OPL, or something else (in which case what)?

Answer (score 2):

You could start with OPL:

```
int n=10;
range N=1..n;


{int} A={1,3,5};

int v[A]=[0,1,2];

range M=1..4;

int b[N][M]=[[1,1]];
int d[A][N]=[[1,2]];

dvar boolean x[A][N][M][N];

subject to
{
  forall(i in N,a in A) sum(j in M,k in N:k <=minl(n,i+v[a])) x[a,i,j,k]*b[k,j]==d[a,i];
}
```